# How to namespace generators that don't live in a Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, thor, rails-generate

I'm confused.

A gem that I used, called [`railsy_backbone`](https://github.com/westonplatter/railsy_backbone), provides sweet namespaced generators. From the command-line I can invoke them thus,

`$ rails g backbone:model widget`

Now, it is time for me to make sweet generators, but I'm having trouble with the namespacing. I've done my research, I've read [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/generators.html), and [this](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2011/05/22/adding-a-namespaced-rails-generator-to-a-standalone-ruby-gem/), and even [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3091909/creating-a-ruby-on-rails-3-gem-with-a-generator-incl-namespace). The structure I ended up with is this:

```
lib/generators/
└── marionette
    └── model
        ├── model_generator.rb
        ├── templates
        └── USAGE
```

The contents of `model_generator.rb` are,

```
module Marionette
  module Generators
    class ModelGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
      source_root File.expand_path('../templates', __FILE__)
    end
  end
end
```

Which mirrors all examples I've read. For comparison, here is the `lib/generators` a partial tree of the `railsy_backbone` gem:

```
generators/
└── backbone
    ├── bob
    │   ├── bob_generator.rb
    │   └── templates
    │       └── model.coffee
    ├── helpers.rb
    ├── model
    │   ├── model_generator.rb
    │   └── templates
    │       └── model.coffee
```

I actually added `backbone:bob` myself, which subsequently shows up in the list of generators under the namespace backbone when I run `rails g` sans arguments. Here, as well, are the contents of `model_generator.rb`,

```
require 'generators/backbone/helpers'

module Backbone
  module Generators
    class ModelGenerator < Rails::Generators::NamedBase
      include Backbone::Generators::Helpers

      source_root File.expand_path("../templates", __FILE__)

      // the implementation

    end
  end
end
```

The only difference I can see between my code and theirs, is that they have packaged their generators in a gem. My generators live in the rails app that I'm working on for the time-being. For now I've given up, and am just going to make a bunch of top-level generators. Eventually, when I'm ready to use them, I will package them as a gem and install it. I expect that will work. However, I'd really like to know how to namespace generators without having them live in a gem. Anyone have any relevant experience?

Comment: I would also love to know how to do this, because I've got a lot of generators on my platform that are all separate right now.

Comment: Ziggy, this might be useful: https://github.com/lastobelus/cleanthor. You can also look in devcloudcoder.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

`$ rails generate generator your_gem_name/generator_name`

Then check:

`$ rails generate your_gem_name:generator_name --help`